# in another language, text typed in console is not the same as the text in the code

Tags: c#, localization, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to ask for input from the console in Hebrew and then compare it to a premade table. Problem is for some reason the text from the console and what i typed in the code aren't the same.

through testing i found that with the following code, if i type א in console, it returns no. Why does it do this and how do i fix it?

```
string t = Console.ReadLine();
if (t == "א")
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else { Console.WriteLine("no"); }
```

Comment: Most likely the console class does not accept unicode, check out the [Console.InputEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.inputencoding?view=net-6.0) property, and try setting that to `Encoding.UTF8` and see what happens.

Comment: i did that, and it still returned no, and also the original program is just as broken as before.

    `using System.Text;
    Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Text;

Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

string t = Console.ReadLine();
if (t == "א")
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no");
}
```

Worked for me copy/pasting א in.